# Independence of discrete random variable from itself (please check and comment on my attempt)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Could you please check and comment my following attempt of a proof:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$ be a probality space and $(E,\mathcal E)$ a measurable space. $E$ countable and $\mathcal E = 2^E$.

Proof the following:

A discrete random variable $X:(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P) \to (E,\mathcal E)$ is independent from itself $\Leftrightarrow$

$\exists x \in E,$ such that $\Bbb P[X=x]=1$ and $\Bbb P[X=y]=0 \forall y\neq x$

My attempt:

$"\Rightarrow"\\$

Assumed, there exists $x,y \in E$ such that $x \neq y$ and $\Bbb P(A_x)>0$ and  $\Bbb P(A_y)>0$ with $A_x,A_y \in \mathcal E$ containing $x$ and $y$, then we have
$$0=\Bbb P[\emptyset] = \Bbb P(A_x \cap A_y)= \Bbb P(A_x) \Bbb P(A_y) >0 ↯$$
$$1=\Bbb P[E] = \Bbb P( \overset{.}{\bigcup}_{x\in E}\{X=x\})= \sum_{x \in E} \Bbb P(X=x)$$

$\Rightarrow \exists !x :$ $\Bbb P[X=x]=1$ and $\forall y= x :\Bbb P[Y=y]=0 $

Because $X$ is independent from itself, it is
$$\Bbb P(X \cap X)= \Bbb P(X) = \Bbb P(X) \cdot \Bbb P(X)$$
$\Rightarrow \Bbb P(X)=\Bbb P^2(X)$
and as  $\Bbb P \in [0,1]$ therefore either $\Bbb P(X)=0$ or $\Bbb P(X)=1$

$"\Leftarrow"$

Let $x,y \in E$ such that $x \neq y$ with $\Bbb P(X=x)=1$ and $\Bbb P(X=y)=0$

Then we have, if  $$\Bbb P(A_x)=0 \Rightarrow \Bbb P(A_x \cap A_y)=0$$
as $\Bbb P \in [0,1]$ and $A_x \cap A_y \subset A_x$ and therefore $\Bbb P(A_x \cap A_y) \leq \Bbb P(A_x)=0$

And if  $$\Bbb P(A_x)=1 \Rightarrow \Bbb P(A_x \cap A_y)=\Bbb P(A_y)$$
as  $A_y= (A_y \cap A_x) \overset{.}{\cup} (A_y \cap A_x^c) $ and $(A_y \cap A_x^c)=0$ because $\Bbb P(A_x^c)=0$

Therefore $\Bbb P(A_y)=\Bbb P(A_y)\cdot\Bbb P(A_x)$ analogously for $A_y$

$\Rightarrow \Bbb P(A_x \cap A_y)=\Bbb P(A_x) \Bbb P(A_y) $

Remark: My mothertongue isn't english and I'm not good at LaTex. I apologize in advance.

Comment: What is $Y$?   (Theorem statement).

Comment: @herbsteinberg thank you, it was a misspelling

Comment: $P(A_x\cap A_y)=P(A_x)P(A_y)$ not true when dependent.

Comment: The equality $\Bbb P(X \cap X)= \Bbb P(X) = \Bbb P(X) \cdot \Bbb P(X)$ doesn't have sence because $X$ is a random variable but not an event.